# Trying to apply Knuth's Mastermind algorithm to my Mastermind project in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been trying to implement Knuth's algorithm to my version of Mastermind, and I got a bit stuck on step 6 of the algorithm. [Here is a link to the steps I'm using.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) (Scroll down a bit)

And here's step 6 copypasted from the link:

> 6  Apply minimax technique to find a next guess as follows: For each
>   possible guess, that is, any unused code of the 1296 not just those in
>   S, calculate how many possibilities in S would be eliminated for each
>   possible colored/white peg score. The score of a guess is the minimum
>   number of possibilities it might eliminate from S. From the set of
>   guesses with the maximum score, select one as the next guess, choosing
>   a member of S whenever possible. (Knuth follows the convention of
>   choosing the guess with the least numeric value e.g. 2345 is lower
>   than 3456. Knuth also gives an example showing that in some cases no
>   member of S will be among the highest scoring guesses and thus the
>   guess cannot win on the next turn, yet will be necessary to assure a
>   win in five.)

Anyway, whenever I'm trying to perform step 6, somewhere in my code a problem seems to occur. The array of possible combinations keeps getting smaller (upwards to 8 on turn 9 on which it shuts down), but it's  no where near as efficient as it should be, because this algorithm should guess the code correctly after 5 turns. I've been looking around and checking the other Knuth algorithm questions on Stackoverflow but I couldn't find my answer in those, so I hoped I could maybe get some more direct help. What I'd basically like to know is **where** my code is malfunctioning, **why**, and **how to fix it.** Any answer will be much appreciated!

This is the code I'm using to generate the next (or first) code that the computer will guess.

In this code, `possibleCombList` functions as my version of 'S' as described in the steps, and `code` functions as my current/next guess.

```
public void generateCode() {

    ArrayList<String> bestGuesses = new ArrayList<String>(); // Create new
                                                                // array in
                                                                // which I
                                                                // store all
                                                                // the best
                                                                // guesses.

    if (totalGuesses == 0) { // If this is the first guess, pick spot 1122
                                // from the array of combinations as my next
                                // code.
        code = possibleCombList.get(1122);
    }

    else if (possibleCombList.size() == 1) { // If there's only one
                                                // combination left in the
                                                // array, pick that one.
        code = possibleCombList.get(0);
    }

    else { // If none of the above are true, do this;
        int tempBlackPins = 0;
        int tempWhitePins = 0;

        possibleCombList.remove(possibleCombList.indexOf(code)); // Remove
                                                                    // last
                                                                    // guess.

        for (int i = 0; i < possibleCombList.size(); i++) { // (Step 5)
                                                            // Delete any
                                                            // code that
                                                            // would not
                                                            // give the same
                                                            // response if
                                                            // the last
                                                            // guess were
                                                            // the code.
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                if (possibleCombList.get(i).charAt(a) == (code.charAt(a))) {
                    tempBlackPins++;
                } else if (possibleCombList.get(i).contains("" + code.charAt(a))) {
                    tempWhitePins++;
                }
            }
            if (tempBlackPins != blackPins && tempWhitePins != whitePins) {
                possibleCombList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        int maxMinimum = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < possibleCombList.size(); j++) { // (Step 6)
                                                            // Apply minMax
                                                            // technique
                                                            // (calculate
                                                            // which codes
                                                            // would
                                                            // eliminate the
                                                            // most
                                                            // possibilities
                                                            // next turn and
                                                            // pick one of
                                                            // those codes).
            int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            tempBlackPins = 0;
            tempWhitePins = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < possibleCombList.size(); i++) {
                for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                    if (possibleCombList.get(i).charAt(a) == (code.charAt(a))) {
                        tempBlackPins++;
                    } else if (possibleCombList.get(i).contains("" + code.charAt(a))) {
                        tempWhitePins++;
                    }
                }
                if (tempBlackPins != blackPins && tempWhitePins != whitePins) {
                    minimum++;
                }
            }

            if (minimum == maxMinimum && minimum > 0) {
                bestGuesses.add(possibleCombList.get(j));
            }

            if (minimum > maxMinimum) {
                maxMinimum = minimum;
                bestGuesses.clear();
                bestGuesses.add(possibleCombList.get(j));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(bestGuesses.size());
        code = bestGuesses.get(0); // Grab position 0 of the array with best
                                    // guesses and make that the next guess.

    }

}
```

Thank you guys for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the way you correct your guess.

Consider this case:
Code: (Red -x - x -x)

Guess: (x - Red - Red - x)

In your evaluation you will get two white pins while it should be only one.